# Best Inno Setup GUI?

Tags: user-interface, inno-setup

There are a few GUIs for Inno Setup out there. I'm just getting into Inno Setup and I'm likely to pick 1 GUI and stick with it. Anyone have any opinions on the best one?

I can also use ISTool even though it is no longer available via downloads, etc. I've had it for a while. Since it's unsupported now though, I would prefer other options.

BTW, for anyone new to Inno Setup use this link to connect to all the supported 3rd party addons for inno [here](http://www.innosetup.com/is3rdparty.php).

Comment: This is a subjective question and [can't really be answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Also note that InnoIDE has been bundled with the Quickstart pack for a while

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup installs are created from install scripts (*.iss files), so all you need is a text editor. I use Inno Setup for all my projects, and I've never used anything more advanced Notepad++. Other than that you might look at InnoIDE, as Deanna said. I've used it but never as anything more than a glorified text editor with syntax highlighting (which Notepad++ has anyway for iss files).